# How to use For loop to cycle through 1 to 10 again and again until the loop is broken in python

Tags: python

What i want to do here is to print the `loop indexes` 1 to 10 and again loop should start from the beginning after index reaches value 10. Also, loop should be broken if the `condition 1` is true. following C++ code below represents the algorithm that i want to implement in python.

```
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    if(true) break;     //condition 1

    cout << i;
    if(i == 10) i = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to repeatedly cycle through an iterable:

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.cycle(range(10)):
    if condition:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Or you can create a generator with an infinite loop:

```
def numbers(num):
    while 1:
        yield from range(num)
```

And then use it:

```
for i in numbers(10):
    if condition:
        break
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: it's not `yield from num(range)` yield from range(num). correct the answer please!

Comment: My bad on that transposition; [sorry Broccoli](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T41gqFO9zb0). Thanks Wombatz.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in itertools.cycle(range(10)):
    if whatever: break
    print i
```

Comment: I think you mean `if condition: break; else: print i`.

Comment: exception  "name 'itertools' is not defined"

Comment: It assumes you did `import itertools` just prior.

Comment: Oh. Now it's working! Thank you for the tip. but still python for loop kind of strange to me. Is this the only option?